# OAuth2 Configuration And Token Questions

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to understand the right OAuth2 flows I can utilize and impact of their decisions. I have a web application configured with OAuth2 Authentication Flow and see the successful authentication. Our web application also exposes 3 other api endpoints for different applications.

For a first pass, I am trying client confidential flow for the API's. So I create additional OAuth2 web applications with an exposed api for each API. I can invoke a call on the IDP (with grant type, client_id, client_secret, and scope(api id))  to get a access token and can invoke the endpoints. A couple of observations/questions :

- It appears that the client confidential flow does not support RBAC in that there is no identity, roles or permissions. (?)
- I dont really understand how scopes are meant to be used for api's
- If I want have RBAC for an API (with multiple clients), am I forced into an authentication code flow? Would I then create users that act like service accounts and have roles and permissions?
- To allow machine to machine interactions, you would have to provide more information to client applications to make a call on the IDP to create an access token.

I guess I am missing the big picture of using OAuth2 in a enterprise with multiple resource servers and web applications. The concept of using access tokens to allow access to resources need a more concrete feel and example for me.

Thanks

Comment: [Start Building - Choose your application type to get started](https://auth0.com/docs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal behind an access token is to deliver secure values (used for authorization) to your APIs in a verifiable way. Therefore, when users are involved, avoid switching to the client credentials flow when calling upstream APIs.

Instead, consider forwarding the user level access token to upstream APIs, if they are all part of the same solution. However, each API should check for its own required audience and scopes.

The audience is a logical grouping of APIs like `api.company.com`. Think of scopes as being areas of your business as follows.

```
internet/sales
commercial/sales
```

It is up to you how you use these ingredients, since OAuth is about protecting business data. As a starting point, keep scopes simple and focus on claims-based authorization. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/api-authorization-design/) says more about this.